# PDO insert statement with variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create an insert statement via PDO with variables but always get following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Jobber/user.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jobber/usercheck.php(3): Users->__construct('steve', 'testt@test.com', 'test', 1) #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Jobber/user.php on line 9
```

this is the code I'm using for it

```
class Users{
        private $connect ;

        function __construct($name,$email,$password,$usertype){
            include("connect.php");
            $startDb = new Connect();
            $this->connect = $startDb->getDb();
            $sqlquery = $this->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `user`( `Username`, `Email`, `Active`, `Password`, `usertype`) VALUES (" + $name + "," +$email +",0," + $password + "," + $usertype + ")");
            $sqlquery->execute();
        }       
    }
```

Is there a problem with the connection or is it something else with the variables?

this is the connect class

```
class Connect{      
        private $host = "localhost:8080";
        private $user = "root";
        private $password = "test";
        private $dbName = "jobber";
        private $db;

        function __construct(){
            try{
                $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobber',$this->user,$this->password);
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo $ex;
            }
        }

        function getDb(){
            if($this->db instanceof PDO){
                return $this->db;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show code for `Connect` class.

Comment: `$startDb->getDb()` is returning null. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Like the error msg says, your code uses something($this->connect, as that's the only place where you're calling prepare()) as a class object which in turn is supposed to have a method named prepare. But $this->connect actually contains null..

Comment: `+` is math in PHP. That also is not how prepared statements are meant to be used. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I saw that in some question that you use :username for example and then an array to pass the variable?

Comment: You also should hash the password.

Comment: Your getDb method returns `$this->db`, but `$this->db` is never set. You could set it in the constructor.

Comment: The constructor needs to do `$this->db = $connection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Connect` class, you have declared `private $db;`, and you return `$this->db` in the `getDb()` method, but you have never assigned it a value. It appears you probably meant to do this in the constructor.

Instead of

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobber',$this->user,$this->password);
```

use

```
$this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobber',$this->user,$this->password);
```

---

In your `Users` class, a more correct way to use the prepared statement would be to prepare an SQL statement with placeholders. You can then either bind your variables to the prepared statement manually with `bindValue`, or pass them to the `execute` method in an array like this:

```
$sqlquery = $this->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` 
         (`Username`, `Email`, `Active`, `Password`, `usertype`) VALUES (?, ?, 0, ?, ?)");
$sqlquery->execute([$name, $email, $password, $usertype]);
```

but, to be honest, the fact that this is happening in in the constructor seems pretty strange to me.

Comment: It's indeed strange, If I think about I know this is not correct but I'm currently playing around check how things work with PDO and PHP